# When do you have to use #{} while referring to variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes if I've defined a a variable, for example

```
xyz="example"
```

and I'd like to refer back to `xyz`, I can either type `xyz` or `#{xyz}` in statements/loops etc.

My question is when do I use `xyz` and when do I use `#{xyz}`? And how do they differ?

Comment: When you use [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation).

Answer (score 1):

`#{}` allows you to use any Ruby expression (not necessarily a variable) inside an interpolating quote (doubly-quoted strings, regular expressions...). It will evaluate the expression, convert the result to a string using the `to_s` method, then insert ("interpolate") the result into the string at that spot.

For example, if you have a string `"Hello, apollo!"` and want to replace the `apollo` with the contents of a variable, you could say `"Hello, #{name}!"`.

You could even put a whole program inside a string:

```
"One plus two equals #{
  def last_name_by_first_name(last_name)
    People.find_by_last_name(last_name).first.first_name
  end
  find_by_last_name('Jack')
}!"
```

or

```
"#{a = 1} + #{b = 2} = #{a + b}"
```

(But please don't do that, it's a horrid way to write code. Sticking with variable look-ups and simple function calls should be enough for most purposes.)

Anywhere outside of a string (or other interpolating quote), `#{}` is an error.

Comment: Outside of a string, `#` starts a comment

Comment: @Stefan: Still, a logic error, if not a syntax one :P as you will not be accessing any variables using it.